# How pass different args to fragment [navigation] Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation, android-safe-args

I have 4 fragment , A,B,C,D
FROM A,B,C I can navigate to D fragment, I want to pass different args from each fragment like,

```
A.Direction.actionNavigation.D(int,String)
B.Direction.actionNavigation.D(float,Bool)
C.Direction.actionNavigation.D(double,String) and etc..
```

I can set all six args in D fragment argument but in this case I should pass all six variable on each direction. so is there other way to pass directly the args which i want on specific direction and then retrieve it in D fragment

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are Navigation Component , you need to make all the arguments that D Fragment demands to be nullable . In this way , you can forward only the particular arg from a particular fragment of your need to the D Fragment.
For doing the same , you need to make changes to the xml file regarding the navigation component , which in general is called nav_graph.xml .

```
<argument
            android:name="fromAtoD"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="true"/>
```

The above changes need to be made to achieve your needs . You need to make null checks to avoid the code from crashing

---

Another approach to this , will be using Intent and passing bundles within Intent, which is not recommended neither is safe .